# Andengine Demo Nullpointer

Tags: android, andengine

I want to create a simple game and i want to use the andengine.

So i decided to test the library with this code:

```
public class PrisonBreakActivity extends BaseGameActivity  {
    
    private ZoomCamera mCamera;
    private BitmapTextureAtlas mTexture;
    private TextureRegion mFaceTextureRegion;
    private Scene mScene;
    
    private static final int CAMERA_WIDTH = 720;
    private static final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 480;
    
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public Engine onLoadEngine() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadResources() {
        this.mTexture = new BitmapTextureAtlas(64, 64, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
        this.mFaceTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.mTexture, this, "gfx/man.png", 0, 0);
         
        this.mEngine.getTextureManager().loadTexture(this.mTexture);
        
    }

    @Override
    public Scene onLoadScene() {
        this.mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());

        this.mScene = new Scene();
        this.mScene.setBackground(new ColorBackground(0.09804f, 0.6274f, 0.8784f));

        this.mScene.setOnSceneTouchListener(new IOnSceneTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(Scene pScene,
                        TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()) {
                        PrisonBreakActivity.this.loadNewTexture();
                }

                return true;
                }
        });

        return this.mScene;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadComplete() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }
    
    private void loadNewTexture() {
        
        MathUtils mu = new MathUtils();
        
         //final TextureRegion faceTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.mTexture, this, "gfx/man.png", 0, 0);
        final float x = (CAMERA_WIDTH - mFaceTextureRegion.getWidth()) * mu.RANDOM.nextFloat();
        final float y = (CAMERA_HEIGHT - mFaceTextureRegion.getHeight()) * mu.RANDOM.nextFloat();
        final Sprite clickToUnload = new Sprite(x, y, mFaceTextureRegion);
        this.mScene.attachChild(clickToUnload);
}
}
```

I allways get a NullPointerException in the library (BaseGameActivity).
The Image man.png is in /asset/gfx/.

```
GameBaseActivity (from Andengine, Error in applyEngineOptions):

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle pSavedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(pSavedInstanceState);
        this.mPaused = true;

        this.mEngine = this.onLoadEngine();

        this.applyEngineOptions(this.mEngine.getEngineOptions());

        this.onSetContentView();
    }
```

Error:

> 04-03 16:22:27.238: E/AndroidRuntime(425):    at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
>
> 04-03 16:22:27.238: E/AndroidRuntime(425):    at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
>
> 04-03 16:22:27.238: E/AndroidRuntime(425):    at
> android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
> 04-03
> 16:22:27.238: E/AndroidRuntime(425):  at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
>
> 04-03 16:22:27.238: E/AndroidRuntime(425):    at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> 04-03
> 16:22:27.238: E/AndroidRuntime(425):  at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
> 04-03 16:22:27.238:
> E/AndroidRuntime(425):    at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
> 04-03
> 16:22:27.238: E/AndroidRuntime(425):  at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
> 04-03
> 16:22:27.238: E/AndroidRuntime(425):  at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
> 04-03 16:22:27.238:
> E/AndroidRuntime(425):    at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
> 04-03 16:22:27.238: E/AndroidRuntime(425):    at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
> 04-03
> 16:22:27.238: E/AndroidRuntime(425):  at
> dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
> 04-03 16:22:27.238:
> E/AndroidRuntime(425): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
> 04-03
> 16:22:27.238: E/AndroidRuntime(425):  at
> org.anddev.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity.onCreate(BaseGameActivity.java:65)
> 04-03 16:22:27.238: E/AndroidRuntime(425):    at
> android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
> 04-03 16:22:27.238: E/AndroidRuntime(425):    at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)

Please help.

Comment: Your null pointer is coming from the class BaseGameActivity. The code you posted isn't what is throwing the error. The line in logcat 'Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at org.anddev.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity.onCreate(BaseGameActivity.java:65)' should be a good hint for where to look. Look at line 65 in BaseGameActivity

Comment: as i wrote above i am using the framework and thats a Standard Class (i don't build it) so the error have to be in my code

Comment: Well, according to the logcat output the error is from the framework. So, either the framework has a bug in it or you are missing a step in your class to setup the base class properly.

Answer (score 3):

Your method

```
public Engine onLoadEngine() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
```

is returning null. Looking at the source code of BaseGameActivity you will see that in the onCreate it tries to set it's mEngine variable by calling 
`this.mEngine = this.onLoadEngine();` which is calling your onLoadEngine() method and returning null

next it tries to access a method from that variable using the call `this.applyEngineOptions(this.mEngine.getEngineOptions());`

since mEngine is null at this point it will throw the null pointer exception.

Complete your onLoadEngine method to properly initialize the Engine and the nullpointerexception will be fixed

Ref: [BaseGameActivity source code](http://code.google.com/p/andengine/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/ui/activity/BaseGameActivity.java)